# Add a hashmap to an array of hashmaps

Tags: java, list, jdbc, hashmap, resultset

I have the following code:

```
    ResultSet rs = DB.doQuery("SELECT username,register_ip FROM users ORDER BY joined DESC LIMIT 10");
    Map<String,String> botInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    List<Map<String , String>> myMap  = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    int c = 0;

    while(rs.next()) {
        botInfo.put("username", rs.getString("username"));
        botInfo.put("register_ip", rs.getString("register_ip"));
        myMap.add(c, botInfo);
        c++;
    }
```

The idea is to have the output be like this.. and I'll use PHP as an example:

```
[0] => array('username' => 'someUsername', 'register_ip' => 'someIP');
```

And so on.. but, what I get is a list of 10 HashMaps that all contain the same username,register_ip value.  What are my options?

Comment: you should use `LinkedList` instead of `ArrayList`, this is why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846183/arraylist-vs-linkedlist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you're adding the same *botInfo* HashMap to your List. What you would want to do is create a new HashMap inside your while loop, add elements to it and finally add this map to your list. What you would want to do is something like this:

```
ResultSet rs = DB.doQuery("SELECT username,register_ip FROM users ORDER BY joined DESC LIMIT 10");
List<Map<String , String>> myMap  = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
int c = 0;

while(rs.next()) {
    //Create a new instance of the map
    Map<String,String> botInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //Add elements to the the map
    botInfo.put("username", rs.getString("username"));
    botInfo.put("register_ip", rs.getString("register_ip"));

    //Add the map to the list
    myMap.add(c, botInfo);

    //Increment your counter
    c++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ResultSet rs = DB.doQuery("SELECT username,register_ip FROM users ORDER BY joined DESC LIMIT 10");
List<Map<String , String>> myMap  = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

while(rs.next()) {
    Map<String,String> botInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    botInfo.put("username", rs.getString("username"));
    botInfo.put("register_ip", rs.getString("register_ip"));
    myMap.add(botInfo);
}
```

You need a new `HashMap` for `botInfo` for every record.

EDIT: `c` was useless

Answer (score 1):

```
ResultSet rs = DB.doQuery("SELECT username,register_ip FROM users ORDER BY joined DESC LIMIT 10");
Map<String,String> botInfo;
List<Map<String , String>> myMap  = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

while(rs.next()) {
    botInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    botInfo.put("username", rs.getString("username"));
    botInfo.put("register_ip", rs.getString("register_ip"));
    myMap.add(botInfo);
}
```

Use this code.. This will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
ResultSet rs = DB.doQuery("SELECT username,register_ip FROM users ORDER BY joined DESC LIMIT 10");
Map<String,String> botInfo;
List<Map<String , String>> myMap  = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
String[] columns = {"username", "register_ip"};

while(rs.next()) {
    botInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        botInfo.put(columns[i], rs.getString(columns[i]));
    }
    myMap.add(botInfo);
}
```